# Link Analytics API to my Google Developers account

Tags: google-analytics-api

When I sign in to Google Developers console and go to the Enabled APIs tab, I see "No enabled APIs". I used to see the Analytics API here and now it's no longer there. That's because the project associated with it is gone.

I believe this happened when I switched my old Google account to the new Google Apps for Work account. It asked me to choose between the two because they had the same email address and I chose to keep the new one.

Unfortunately the old one had all the Developers APIs associated with it. :(

The Analytics API is still working, it's just no longer associated to my account. Is it possible to link it back to my account?

Thanks for your help,

Philip

PS. I can provide my Google email account and the Google Analytics API client id on request if needed.

Comment: Have you tried logging into the original account and adding the work account as owner then you should be able to see it in Google developers console.

Comment: The original account no longer exists. When I signed up for Google Apps for Work it made me choose between the two and it deleted the old account. :(

Comment: If the analytics API is still working I don't think its deleted.  If the project was deleted from Google developers console it would no longer work.

Comment: The project may not be deleted, but I can definitely no longer access my old account. Can the project be linked back to my new account?

Comment: No idea try contacting the Google Apps for work or create a new project on Google Developers console.   This isn't really a programing issue its an issue with the Google developers console the product.  You are going to have to contact them.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its an issue with a google account and is not really programing related even if the account is used to create projects.  OP should contact Google.

Comment: Thanks for your help DaImTo, I really appreciate it. Any idea how I can contact Google about this? The Adwords and Analytics support at Google pointed me to these forums.

Comment: Not really but I have sent out a few emails to Googlers who might be able to help linking your question. This isn't the first time I have seen this question over the last few weeks and I am curious as to what is causing the problem.  Unfortunately its the only thing I can do to help at this time.  You have a slight chance they may respond sorry I cant be of more help.

Comment: PM for Google Apps for work has now been pinged.   What they do next is anyones guess.